# What's the best way to abort a thread in my scenerio

Tags: c#, multithreading, abort

I'm sorry if some other people have asked a similar question before. 
I have a simple GUI app which upload some files to a server. I put the upload work to a seperate thread. When users want to exit the application, a event will be set to notify the thread to exit normally. Then the UI thread will wait for it. The code I used to abort the thread is as follows:-

```
if (mUploadThread != null) {
  if (mStopUploadEvent.WaitOne(0, true)) {
   string message = @"A normal cancellation may take a couple of minutes. Are you sure you want forcibly abort?";
   string caption = @"Warning";
   if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)) {
    mUploadThread.Abort();
   }

  } else {
   mStopUploadEvent.Set();
  }

  do {
   Application.DoEvents();
  } while (!mUploadThread.Join(1000));
 }
```

Here I want to terminate the worker thread if the user do want to. But the abort() method just doesn't work. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: if you mark your worker thread as background, you don't need to abort it yourself - it won't prevent the app from exiting.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how are you uploading? `Thread.Abort` is *rarely* a sensible choice - it can leave you `AppDomain` (or even `Process`) in a completely messed-up state. If you are uploading via http, you could try using the async methods, allowing you to call `HttpWebRequest.Abort`, which is a bit more friendly.

Comment: fully agree on not using Thread.Abort normally, but it sounds like this is a scenario where he's about to exit the entire process anyway AFAICT.

Comment: I know Abort is not a good choice, that's why I use event to notify the thread to exit first. Yes I think I should use the async http methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, this is just to add to what Marc said, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710070/timeout-pattern-how-bad-is-thread-abort-really/710094#710094) might help understand why `.Abort` is not so a good choice.

Comment: Which he does... `do { Application.DoEvents(); } while (!mUploadThread.Join(1000));`

Comment: @Marc: Missed that part; removed from my answer.